# How can I make a DynamicUser's StateDirectory readable by another user?

Tags: systemd

Suppose I have nginx running under systemd like so:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
[Unit]
Description=nginx - high performance web server
Documentation=https://nginx.org/en/docs/
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c "/bin/kill -s HUP $(/bin/cat /var/run/nginx.pid)"
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c "/bin/kill -s TERM $(/bin/cat /var/run/nginx.pid)"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And another service that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=...
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=unitname
Group=unitname
DynamicUser=true

StateDirectory=unitname
PrivateTmp=true

ExecStart=somecommand
```

How can I give access to `/var/lib/unitname` (a link to `/var/lib/private/unitname`) to the `nginx` user, (which `nginx` drops privileges and switches to)?